# How do I stretch this sprite in tiled mode Unity without repeating from the bottom part of the sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, game-development

Here is the sprite in it's original form:
[image: Form 1]

Now when I increase the height of this image through the sprite renderer's height it looks like this and repeats in a zig zag pattern like this and it's repeating itself in a zigzag pattern just like I want it to but as you can see the highlighted area It's repeating from the arrow again what I want is that it repeats from this part, look at the 3rd image
[image: Image 2]

Look how in this image the sprite is repeating itself from the line which is at the top instead of starting from the arrow again, I want it to repeat in same zigzag pattern but not including the arrow again, and yes I know that I can create a seperate sprite for the arrow but even if I do that you can see in the first image that the line in the sprite does not starts from the very bottom of the sprite so seperating the arrow as a different sprite would make the repeatition have the same gap too.

[image: Image 3]

Comment: Have you considered using two sprites, one with the arrow and one with only the white line?

Comment: @MaxPlay yes I know that I can create a seperate sprite for the arrow but even if I do that you can see in the first image that the line in the sprite does not starts from the very bottom of the sprite so seperating the arrow as a different sprite would make the repeatition have the same gap too, look at the last image I want it continue repeating with the line at the top joining the new repition without any gap in between

Comment: I am not talking about the arrow. Did you even read my comment? One sprite with the arrow and one with just the line. Just spawn the one with the line after the other one and repeat that.